# How to check if given interval [a, b) contains an integer, divisible by x?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, algorithms

This might seem/appear to be homework question, but is not. 
This problem appeared in one of coding competition site (which should have made me post this question on https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/, however, I posted here because of the mathematical nature of this question), and I just can't get around solving this question.

To explain the question in more detail - 
You will be given a range, [a, b) (left-bound included, right-bound not included), and a number x. This range can be expanded as ->

a, a+1, a+2, a+3, ... n ..., b-3, b-2, b-1.

We need to find a number, n, if it exists, that is divisible by x.

For eg, x = 1000 -

1. [999;1002) -> returns true
2. [1002;1009) -> returns false
3. [1:1003) -> return true.

Comment: Your examples seem not to say what value of $x$ to use in each case. (Hopefully we understood the problem despite this.)

Comment: Oh ya! I curated the examples based on a value of x which I completely forgot to mention.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest way to check this is to check whether there is an integer $n$ with $\frac{a}{x}\le n<\frac{b}{x}$.

You only have to check, whether $ceil(\frac{a}{x})$ , which is the smallest integer greater than or equal to $\frac{a}{x}$, is smaller than $\frac{b}{x}$. If and only if this is the case, an integer $n$ with the desired property exists.